# Installing an HP Laserjet 1000

Tags: printing

I've already installed hplip, it printed a test page, but it won't print from any program. It shows the printer in the list of printers, and it's checked as the default printer. I've restarted a couple times.

When I plugged the USB cable for the printer into the computer after installing hplip, it said printer detected. Then after a couple seconds it said the printer was ready for use.

When I send something to the printer, a pop-up shows that a document was sent to the printer - but there's a triangle with an exclamation point in it next to the message. A few seconds another pop-up indicates that the printer has completed printing the job but it didn't print anything.

Comment: Do you notice that, when you turn on the printer, it first makes some noises, then stops, and then rumbles again? In linux, when you turn on the printer, the last thing it does is loading the firmware in the printer. If the firmware isn't loaded, the printer won't work.

Double check with hplip to load the firmware to the printer again.

Comment: You need to patch the hplip driver - I had to do so for mine. I'll post the patch and the new deb install later today.

Comment: I did get my printer to work, but it prints blank pages, and it doesn't stop printing. Will the patch work for this too? Please give instructions, as I'm kinda new to Ubuntu. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

I'm glad you asked this because it took me quite some time to figure it out myself. `hplip` doesn't support the HP Laserjet 1000 without patching - which is unfortunate because it's a pretty affordable and a pretty decent printer. In order to get the `hplip` drivers to work you need to patch them with [this patch](https://answers.launchpad.net/hplip/+question/129562).  You'll also need to install these dependencies first:

```
sudo apt-get install libcups2 cups libcups2-dev cups-bsd cups-client libcupsimage2-dev libdbus-1-dev build-essential ghostscript openssl libjpeg62-dev libsnmp-dev libtool libusb-dev python-imaging policykit-1 policykit-1-gnome python-qt4 python-qt4-dbus python-dbus python-gobject python-dev python-notify python python-reportlab libsane libsane-dev sane-utils xsane
```

Once those dependencies are installed - you'll need to download the source for hplip, I can't confirm that it works for the latest version, however I have successfully patched 3.10.9

If you're unfamiliar with patching I have patched the source for hplip and made it [available for download](http://marcoceppi.com/au/hplip-3.10.9.marco.tar.gz).

Once you've patched hplip continue the installation by running `./install.py` and follow the onscreen instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I've had since Natty problems with the hplip drivers and my LJ 1018.

I've set up Oneiric this week, running into the same problem with hplip again, and that it was unable to download the firmware.

I've solved it using foo2zjs. A description how I've done it in detail is here: https://plus.google.com/u/0/112161258221779145276/posts/imgVhbXxRWC

Answer (score 0):

*Considering you have 1 "HP LaserJet 1000" printer connected to your USB and 0 such printers already addded.*

*Tested on Ubuntu 18.04*

**Before this set-up, I've installed (but not sure if makes difference) `hp-ppd`
(installed with `sudo apt install hp-ppd`).**

I had to install hplip (which you already did) with

```
sudo apt install hplip
```

With this pure installation, firmware installation always failed for me, first I had to do

```
hp-firmware -i
```

This command **takes a while** (like few seconds) - should end with simple "`Done.`"

Then when I finally ran

```
hp-setup -ia
```

and selected usb (enter for default enter=usb* option), it all went well without any errors ending again with the simple "`Done.`".

**- after this, printer started printing :)**

Another thing I am not sure if it made a difference or not, but I've also installed some dependencies from [@Marco Ceppi answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/48284/277898) (replacing `python-imaging` with `python-pil` though). **However**,
**I did not install the patch he described**.

*Sidenote:*
<sub>*Already tried to install this printer? If you **don't** have any other existing printers - remove the old with `hp-setup -ir` (repeat untill it tells you error No device found - that is the printer-clean state).*</sub>